# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mnist'

Tags: python, jupyter, mnist

I am trying to import a locale MNIST dataset from my computer into Jupyter Notebook, but i am getting a ModuleNotFound error.

I have installed the python-mnist package

```
# Import necessary modules 
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from mnist import MNIST

import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

mnist = MNIST('../Dataset/MNIST')
x_train, y_train = mnist.load_training() #60000 samples
x_test, y_test = mnist.load_testing()    #10000 samples
```

```
THE ERROR MESSAGE
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-4e881af1c89c> in <module>
      2 from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
      3 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
----> 4 from mnist import MNIST
      5 
      6 import numpy as np

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mnist'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
datasets = tfds.load('mnist')

train_dataset = datasets['train']
test_dataset = datasets['test']

IMAGE_INPUT_NAME = 'image'
LABEL_INPUT_NAME = 'label'
```

https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/overview

Answer (score 1):

You can directly fetch the database from `tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()` as well.

Here is the code for that.

```
import tensorflow as tf

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

print([i.shape for i in (x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test)])
```

```
[(60000, 28, 28), (60000,), (10000, 28, 28), (10000,)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you must install

> python-mnist

see this link:
[python-mnist 0.7](https://pypi.org/project/python-mnist/)

Comment: Use this to install the above package: `pip install python-mnist`